# ps aux | grep x returns two root instances

Tags: python, unix, cron, raspberry-pi, ps

I have a python script that starts on reboot using cron @reboot. When I use `ps aux | grep x.py` it returns two root instances and one user (in this case the user is pi) instance.

Is this a problem? How do I make sure there's only one instance?

Example:
root   2317 0.0 0.3 4584 1484 pts/0    S+  0.00 sudo python /home/pi/Twitter.py
root   2318 36.5 3. 7 52072 16952 pts/0    S1+  4.26 python /home/pi/Twitter.py

Comment: try `ps aux | grep [x].py`

Comment: This isn't clear. Can you show the relevant output?

Comment: You might want to look at `pgrep`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That works in getting rid of the user instance (the grep instance matching itself) The problem is actually something else. When the script is run it seems to run two root instances. The one command is running from sudo python x.py and the second is just python x.py

The interesting thing is that the time that the sudo python version is running for is 0:00 while the python version is consistently running.

I have added an example to the question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get two instances is because the grep sees both the `x.py` and the `grep x.py` processes.

The best way to do this is to use `pgrep x.py` or you can use the trick of making your grep expression not match itself such as `ps -aux | grep [x].py`.

WRT your followup comments:  What happens when you run sudo, is that it creates another process.  ps shows this process and sudo because they both have the string you are searching for in their argument list.

If you look at the output of ps you should see something like this:

```
0 62379   445   0  9:48pm ttys003    0:00.02 sudo x.py
0 62383 62379   0  9:48pm ttys003    0:00.01 x.py
```

Notice that the sudo has a process id of `62379` and x.py has a parent process id of `62379` which tells you it was started by sudo.  The sudo process just sits there waiting for its child process to complete.  It doesn't have any significant impact on the performance of your computer.

I guess there are probably a few ways you can exclude the sudo process from your list.  The easiest one I can think of is:

```
ps -eaf | grep [x].py | grep -v sudo
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That works in getting rid of the user instance (the grep instance matching itself) The problem is actually something else. When the script is run it seems to run two root instances. The one command is running from sudo python x.py and the second is just python x.py The interesting thing is that the time that the sudo python version is running for is 0:00 while the python version is consistently running. I have added an example to the question above